# Duda Consulta SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, sql

Tengo una tabla que me almacena que me almacena tres numeros y un ID.

```
NUMERO1    NUMERO2    NUMERO3    ID  
 14070     4641       24155      1  
 14070     4780       24155      2  
 14070     4333       24155      3  
 15000     4303       24000      2  
 16000     4003       17000      1
```

Me gustaria sacar aquellos registros que tengan mismo numero1 y numero 3 pero con mas de un ID. Es decir me gustaria sacar unicamente estos tres registros

```
 NUMERO1    NUMERO2    NUMERO3    ID   
 14070       4641       24155     1   
 14070       4780       24155     2   
 14070       4333       24155     3
```

He probado con la siguiente consulta, pero no me funciona, no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal

```
SELECT 
    NUMERO1, NUMERO2, NUMERO3, ID 
FROM 
    TABLA 
GROUP BY 
    (NUMERO1, NUMERO3, ID) 
HAVING 
    COUNT(ID)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

No debería ser así:

```html
SELECT 
    NUMERO1, NUMERO2, NUMERO3, ID 
FROM 
    TABLA 
GROUP BY 
    (NUMERO1, NUMERO3) 
HAVING 
    COUNT(ID)>1
```

Quitando el ID del GROUP BY creo que obtiene el resultado que buscas.